# Have any identifier case readability studies been done?

Tags: language-agnostic, readability, naming-conventions

Different languages have different standards for identifier casing. Most discussion I see about this subject revolves around a specific language, and is loaded with personal opinions. And these strong opinions all stem from the decision of one person or a group of people who created the language.

I'd love to see a graph showing just how much more readable `words_per_minute` is than `wordsperminute`. Obviously I'm most interested in the more controversial cases such as `wordsPerMinute`. I suspect the most readable ones take the most time to type, and vice versa, but of course I can't be sure of this on my own.

Have there been any language-agnostic studies done comparing readability of different capitalization schemes? Stats on speed of typing would also be welcome.

Comment: I suspect this will actually be somewhat language-dependent. For example, when writing OO-style with special syntax for receiver (i.e. the traditional `foo.bar()` style), I find that `_` and `.` get somewhat mixed up, so I prefer `camelCase` or `PascalCase` for readability (as `.` in long call chains stands out really well that way). On the other hand, when all I have is plain function calls, then `underscore_separated` seems to be better. Of course this is subjective experience, but it may well have factual underpinnings.

Comment: I have the same impression as Pavel. When I write some C, even after months of C# with underscore allergy, I always go back to `lowercase_with_underscores`, because it just... *feels* better.

Answer (score 1):

Your question reminds me of [this blog post](http://shape-of-code.coding-guidelines.com/2009/01/readability-an-experimental-view/).
Title: **Readability, an experimental view**

Answer (score 1):

I recall there was a paper on that topic at ICPC 2009 in Vancouver, but I was not convinced by their evaluation approach.

The PDF can be found here: http://www.cs.loyola.edu/~binkley/papers/icpc09-clouds.pdf

They showed a screen with moving words and folks at to click as fast as possible on given sentences (once using underscores and once camel-case). This is (sorry to say) a pointless evaluation approach for several reasons, among them that source code does not move, and that it would be much more interesting to learn about the readability in the context of source code with all its operators and other special characters!

PS: *interestingly enough there are some languages that use case as part of their syntax! Haskell, Ruby, and Self are among those I know of.*

Answer (score 0):

I've seen a few citations, but tracking down real studies seems to be quite difficult. I've seen only [one](http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~weimer/p/weimer-issta2008-readability.pdf) or [two](http://www.coding-guidelines.com/cbook/sent792.pdf) available online that seem to have any real supporting evidence.

Comment: I'm sorry if your English is correct but I'm struggling to understand it :(. Do you mean "they seem to have some supporting evidence" or "they don't seem to have any supporting evidence".

Comment: Those two do seem to have some supporting evidence. Most do not.